# Asp.net Dynamically recreating ListBoxes on PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create dynamically added `ListBoxes` based on Main Categories and Subcategories where they can be an infinite amount of sub categories. I have been working on this all week and can't figure this out.

I want it to be like Ebay category selection. When the page loads there will be a listbox with all the main categories. When a user selects an item in the listbox, another listbox should be added dynamically such that each listbox has the selected item still there. So after selected the first item in the first listbox there should be two listboxes with the second listbox showing all subcategories that belong to the one selected. Please see screenshot.

[Ebay Category Selection Example http://www.aquariumbids.com/Images/ebayCat.JPG](http://www.aquariumbids.com/Images/ebayCat.JPG)

**CODE PER REQUEST** 
- Its close to working I think.

```
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private Int32 controlCount = 0;
    Panel _panel;

    private Panel PanelPlaceholder
    {
        get
        {
            if (_panel == null && Master != null)
                _panel = pnlContainer;
            return _panel;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.EnsureChildControls();

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            // Re-create controls but not from datasource
            // The controlCount value is output in the page as a hidden field during PreRender.
            controlCount = Int32.Parse(Request.Form["controlCount"]); // assigns control count from persistence medium (hidden field)         
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < controlCount; i++)
            {
                CreateDynamicControlGroup(false);
            }
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // create from data query.
        // only if not postback
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            int cc = controlCount;

            DataTable dt = null;                
            Dictionary<string, string> Params = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dt = Globals.g_DatabaseHandler.GetRecords(StoredProcedures.GetMainCategories, Params);

            // create a set of dynamic controls for the Row, incrementing counter and 
            // getting a reference to the new controls via their common parent (Dynamic PlaceHolder)
            CreateDynamicControlGroup(true);

            ListBox lb = (ListBox)PanelPlaceholder.Controls[controlCount - 1];

            // On reload you will see that child ListItems are persisted by the DropDownList
            lb.DataSource = dt; // use the same table
            lb.DataValueField = "ID";
            lb.DataTextField = "Name";
            lb.DataBind();
        }
    }


    protected void Page_PreRender(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // persist control count
        ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("controlCount", controlCount.ToString());
    }


    private void ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;


        Dictionary<string, string> Params = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Params.Add("parentID", lb.SelectedValue);
        DataTable Categories = Globals.g_DatabaseHandler.GetRecords(StoredProcedures.GetChildCategories, Params);

        if (Categories.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            // create a set of dynamic controls for the Row, incrementing counter and 
            // getting a reference to the new controls via their common parent (Dynamic PlaceHolder)
            CreateDynamicControlGroup(true);

            ListBox newLb = (ListBox)PanelPlaceholder.Controls[controlCount - 1];
            // On reload you will see that child ListItems are persisted by the DropDownList
            newLb.DataSource = Categories; // use the same table
            newLb.DataValueField = "ID";
            newLb.DataTextField = "Name";
            newLb.DataBind();
        }
    }


    private void CreateDynamicControlGroup(Boolean incrementCounter)
    {
        // Create one logical set of controls do not assign values!
        ListBox lb = new ListBox();
        lb.AutoPostBack = true;
        lb.CssClass = "panel";
        PanelPlaceholder.Controls.Add(lb);

        // wire event delegate
        lb.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged);

        if (incrementCounter)
        {
            controlCount += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
 <div class="Column12" id="Form_NewListing">
    <h2 class="h2row">Create Your Listing - Step 1 of 2)</h2>
    <h3 class="h3row">Select a category</h3>
    <div class="panel">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>        

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Might want to post some code. My guess right now without seeing anything is that you're adding the controls without checking to see if a postback has occured but without code...

Comment: It's almost working with the above code. The thing I am seeing is if I select on previous ListBoxes, the ones that are children dont remove or update themselves.

Comment: What I mean by almost working, the above code will generate dynamic Listboxes based on the previous listboxes selection

Comment: Alright after further testing, its working partly. The ListBoxes are getting recreated on Postback. The problem I am seeing now is If there are 4 Listboxes and the user clicks on an new item in ListbOx 3 the 4th should rerender with the subcategories to its selected parent. i hope I am explaining myself correctly.

Comment: @MikeBrown Any updates on this? Would be interesting to see an answer to this question even though it's 3 years old now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without a postback, here is an article that might help:
Steps to create a cascading drop-down list by using the Microsoft ASP.NET AJAX framework
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976156

Comment: I want ListBoxes for Each Category and all Subcategories like the Image shown.